# Cascading Select with jCombo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want create a triple nested select but first of all i try a simple select.

But the select remain blank.

Can you gime me some hint?

this is my page:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jcombo.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<select name="list1" id="list1"></select><br />
<!--<select name="list2" id="list2"></select><br />
<select name="list3" id="list3"></select>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() { 
 {
    $("#list1").jCombo("getBuilding.php", { selected_value : '1' } );
    //$("#list2").jCombo("getStates.php?id_country=", { parent: "#list1" });    
 //   $("#list3").jCombo("getCities.php?id_state=", { parent: "#list2" });
});</script>
</body></html>
```

where my getBuilding.php is:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconnection.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!db_server) die("Unable to connection_aborted to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database) or die ("Unable to connection_aborted to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 

    // Esegui query nel giusto ordine 
    //(value,text)
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Building";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $items = array();
   if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $option = array("id" => $row[0], "value" => htmlentities($row[1]));
            $items[] = $option;
        }        
    }
    mysql_close();
    $data = json_encode($items);
    // convertire in formato JSON e stampare
    $response = isset($_GET['callback'])?$_GET['callback']."(".$data.")":$data;
    echo($response);   
?>
```

this page works. i obtain the data formatted correctly.

[{"id":"1","value":"Building1"},{"id":"2","value":"Building2"},{"id":"4","value":"Building3"},{"id":"5","value":"Building4"}]
but it not appear in the select.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that firefox is not compatible with jcombo.. it works with explorer of chrome!